# Shell script for ruby scripts execution

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I have a ruby script name analysis and I am executing from bash by passing parameters

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
script here
```

execution:

```
./analysis -d parameter1 -p parameter2 parameter3
```

I execute this script multiple times by passing different parameters each time.
Is there is a way to execute these multiple ruby scripts from shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shell script like this should work:

```
# Execute Ruby script multiple times with different parameters.

ruby ./analysis.rb -d parameter1 -p parameter2 parameter3
ruby ./analysis.rb -d parameter4 -p parameter5 parameter6
ruby ./analysis.rb -d parameter7 -p parameter8 parameter9
```

To pass the variables to the Ruby script via the Bash script arguments:

```
# Include 9 arguments when calling the Bash script. Ruby script will be executed 3 times, with 3 of the arguments each time.
ruby ./analysis.rb $1 $2 $3
ruby ./analysis.rb $4 $5 $6
ruby ./analysis.rb $7 $8 $9
```

Comment: Can I also pass parameters to this shell script?

Answer (score 0):

For each invocation of your script, you can add 1 line, with all 3 parameters, to a file, say, `params.txt`. For e.g.,

```
run1-param1 run1-param2 run1-param3
run2-param1 run2-param2 run2-param3
run3-param1 run3-param2 run3-param3
...
```

Then you can create another bash script, say, `repeat-analysis.sh` that reads 1 line every time and runs `analysis.rb` with the parameters on that line. Example script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p1 p2 p3; do
    ./analysis.rb -d "$p1" -p "$p2" "$p3"
done
```

You can run this script as follows:

```
$ ./repeat-analysis.sh < params.txt
```

An important caveat here is that this will only work if your parameters don't have spaces within them. Let me know if that is not true for you and I can try to improve the script above to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Worked for me. In my case there are no spaces for parameters.